# Can not load image from Facebook

Tags: swift, facebook-graph-api

I want to get my avatar image from Facebook, I have tried like this:

```
import UIKit
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKit
import FBSDKShareKit
import FBSDKMessengerShareKit

class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var avatarImageView: UIImageView!
    var id = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        addBackgroundImage()

        let accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()
        if accessToken != nil {
            print(accessToken.tokenString)
        }

//        let req = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"email,name"], tokenString: accessToken.tokenString, version: nil, HTTPMethod: "GET")
//        req.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error : NSError!) -> Void in
//            error == nil ? print("result \(result)") : print("error \(error)")
//        })

        returnUserData()

    }

    func returnUserProfileImage(accessToken: NSString)
    {
        var userID = accessToken as NSString
        var facebookProfileUrl = NSURL(string: "http://graph.facebook.com/\(userID)/picture?type=large")

        if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: facebookProfileUrl!) {
            avatarImageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
        }

    }

    func returnUserData()
    {
        let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: nil)
        graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in

            if ((error) != nil)
            {
                // Process error
                print("Error: \(error)")
            }
            else
            {
                print("fetched user: \(result)")

                if let id: NSString = result.valueForKey("id") as? NSString {
                    print("ID is: \(id)")
                    self.returnUserProfileImage(id)
                } else {
                    print("ID es null")
                }


            }
        })
    }

    func addBackgroundImage() {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size)
        UIImage(named: "blur_background")?.drawInRect(self.view.bounds)
        let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: image)
    }
}
```

But it says:

> 2016-04-10 22:41:51.400 GiftsToMyFriends[14444:260220] FBSDKLog:
>   starting with Graph API v2.4, GET requests for /me should contain an
>   explicit "fields" parameter fetched user: {
>       id = 942489539201413;
>       name = "\U0110\U0103ng Kh\U01b0\U01a1ng Ph\U1ea1m"; } ID is: 942489539201413
>
> 2016-04-10 22:41:51.639 GiftsToMyFriends[14444:260381] App Transport
>   Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it
>   is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's
>   Info.plist file.

My Info.plist already add this:

[image]

And the image not appear on my ViewController.